# Short stay in France while remote working for a US company (French citizen)

Tags: usa, french-citizens

Currently living in the US, I would like to travel to France for a maximum of 6 months and continue working remotely (French citizen with US L1 VISA).

How should I declare taxes?
Should I declare taxes only to US?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to (my reading of) [the tax treaty between France and the US](https://www.impots.gouv.fr/portail/files/media/10_conventions/etats-unis/etats-unis_convention-avec-les-etats-unis-impot-sur-le-revenu-impot-sur-la-fortune_fd_1835.pdf), you would only be taxed in the US provided:

- you're staying in France for a maximum of 183 days during the whole year. That's roughly six months so you should be fine but you should make sure you're not staying a little more than six months and also include any holidays or visits to France you might make during the rest of the year.
- your employer doesn't have a presence in France.

As a general rule in France, you cannot be fined by the tax office if you did not owe any taxes so not being taxable effectively means you don't have to file a return (unless you have some property in France or French-sourced income beside your salary).